# There is no webpack.mix.js in my node_modules

Tags: npm, webpack, node-modules, laravel-mix

After installing laravel mix via terminal and running the command cp node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.mix.js ./ I'm getting this error.

```
cp : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\COBNETCKNN\Local Sites\portofolio\app\p
ublic\wp-content\themes\wp-portofolio\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\we 
At line:1 char:1
+ cp node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.mix.js ./
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\COBNET...\webp  
   ack.mix.js:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comman  
   ds.CopyItemCommand
```

I also looked inside `node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/` and there was no `webpack.mix.js` so I couldn't pull it from there, did the directory changed or what happened? Can I copy `webpack.mix.js` from my previous projects and modify it for my needs?

Answer (score 2):

For non-Laravel standalone projects, you should do the following.

```
mkdir my-app && cd my-app
npm init -y
npm install laravel-mix --save-dev
```

Create a Mix config file within the root of your project.

```
touch webpack.mix.js
```

Open webpack.mix.js and add the following code:

```
// webpack.mix.js

let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('src/app.js', 'dist').setPublicPath('dist');
```

Compile with `npx mix` or `npm run dev`.

Your webpack.mix.js should not be in /node-modules, it needs to be in the root of your project instance.

Your package.json should look more like the following with the latest version of Laravel Mix.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.4",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.11",
        "postcss": "^8.2.4",
        "sass": "^1.32.6",
        "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation... But someone should really update installation process documentation on their site. https://laravel-mix.com/docs/4.0/installation

Answer (score -1):

Managed to solve it by lowering version of the Laravel Mix, it looks like in latest version you just don't get webpack.mix.js in your node_modules after installing laravel mix, something that should be tackled by the team... So solution for this is that inside your package.json file copy these dependencies below

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.9",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "sass": "^1.30.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1"
  }
```

This is from my old project package.json file, after setting this up you just install laravel mix again via `npm install laravel-mix --save-dev` and then run `cp node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.mix.js ./` which will pull `webpack.mix.js` from your node_modules

Comment: webpack.mix.js should not be inside /node-modules. You need to create it inside your project root.

Comment: @KarlHill Create how?

Comment: Laravel version 8 was the last to use it so you can grab kit from here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/webpack.mix.js