# webpack.mix.js is missing from my new Laravel projects

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, composer-php, laravel-mix

I am new to Laravel and I have run into an issue that when I create a new project either with the `laravel new` or the `composer create-project laravel/laravel` commands, there will be no `webpack.mix.js` file created into my project.

When the creation is finished there is info that `No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].`.

I have no idea how to fix it.

I am using Windows 10 with PHP 8.1.11 version.

I have tried to run `composer update` and tried to do some fixes to this issue: [There is no webpack.mix.js in my node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035964/there-is-no-webpack-mix-js-in-my-node-modules), but none of them helped.

Comment: Newer versions of Laravel are shipped with something called `vite`. If you want to use webpack, use Laravel 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's time to learn how to use `Laravel vite`.

[Check the documentation on the Laravel website here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite)

Or if you want to migrate to laravel mix check here:

> https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md#migrating-from-vite-to-laravel-mix

Check this question too :

[there is no webpack.mix.js file in my laravel project root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73208852/there-is-no-webpack-mix-js-file-in-my-laravel-project-root)